# How to convert logical sparse matrix into integer sparse matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have a matrix https://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/matrices/Hamm/add20.html
I want to consider it as adjacency matrix of corresponding graph, so I'm replacing every non zero element with 1:

```
A = A ~- 0
```

Now I want to calculate A*A
but I can't because

```
>> A*A    
Error using *
Both logical inputs must be scalar.
To compute elementwise TIMES, use TIMES (.*) instead
```

and I for some reason I cannot just convert logical matrix to integer

```
>> uint(A)
Error using numerictype (line 172)
Invalid arguments (WordLength must be a scalar numeric value).

Error in fixdt (line 186)
        embeddedType = numerictype( varargin{:} );

Error in uint (line 14)
DataType = fixdt(0,WordLength,0);
```

I could do it by converting matrix to full rank back and forth but this is impractical for my task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you would want to be using `uint8` or similar, as opposed to `uint` - read the help files as to what the difference is, `uint` doesn't do what you think it does. However, according to [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/274922) forum post, the only valid sparse data types are `double` or `logical`. You've got a logical matrix, but it would appear that sparse matrix multiplication is not defined for logical matrices. Thus, you must convert `A` to double form before you will be able to multiply it as you are trying to.

Alternatively, use `A^2` instead - this will work with logical sparse matrices. Don't know why it's different.

Comment: Thank you for the response. A^2 looks strange indeed, it would be interesting to see why it works...

Comment: @Moonwalker: the result of `A^2` is a double so `mpower` likely converts `A` beforehand (and the result can thus be greater than one of course). Not sure why `mtimes` doesn't do the same.